# python module .exe looking at wrong directory

Tags: python, installation, exe

I'm trying to download pandas from an executable. I have 32 bit python in a folder on my C Drive "C:/Python27". When I go to run the pandas 32 bit .exe it keeps wanting to download the module into "C:/Python28" on my C drive. Awhile back I had both the 32 bit and 64 bit python on my computer. I placed the 32 bit in "C:/python28". But since I have uninstalled the 64 bit version and re-installed the 32bit version into the folder "C:/python27". My path variable and env variable are both pointing to "C:/Python27", I dont undestand where this .exe is getting Python28 as the folder, the folder isn't even in my C drive anymore. I have also installed other .exe's before without anyproblem into my Python27 folder with my 32 bit python

Comment: Maybe check the registry in Winodws and search for the string Python28 to replace it with Python27? Regedit.

Comment: Consider installing visa pip rather than an executable.